# Regular expression to match end punctuation taking abbreviations into account

Tags: .net, regex

I'm trying to construct a regular expression that would match the punctuation characters in a sentence. I want this regular expression to avoid matching the periods belonging to abbreviations.
Example sentence:

```
To get more info, help, etc. read through this manual.
```

In this sentence the regular expression should match all commas and periods except for the "etc." one.
To achieve this I have a list of common English abbreviations and the current state of my regular expression is (I have shortened the list of abbreviations for clarity):

```
(?i)((?<!a\.d|a\.m|abbr|adj|adv|al|etc)(\.)|[,;:!?])$
```

This regular expression is run against each word, the sentence is previously split by spaces.
The problem with this approach is that actually is not skipping the abbreviations as "a whole", in fact, the dot after "manual" is not matched because it ends with "al" which is in the list of abbreviations.
How can I modify the expression to match the end dot only if **the whole word** is not on the list of abbreviations?

Comment: Check with word boundary `\b` prior to English abbreviations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inserting a \b will cause a match only on word boundaries.

For example, `(?i)((?<!((\b)(a\.d|a\.m|abbr|adj|adv|al|etc)))(\.)|[,;:!?])$`

Comment: Inserting \b before each abbreviation? like \badv|\bal|\betc? That seems to work but isn't there a more elegant way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Hmm no, that last edit doesn't match the dot in "manual." or "annual." for example

Comment: A little bug here. There shouldn't be `$` in the end. It will match only last occurrence of punctuation.

Comment: The $ is actually ok, as I stated in the question description, the sentence is first divided into words and then the regex is run for each word.

Comment: Put \b to front of `a\.d` `a\.m`also, then it will be perfect I believe.

Comment: @FranCasadome I haven't tried this but you could try this: (?I)((?<!((\b)(a\.d|a\.m|abbr|adj|adv|al|etc)))(\.)|[,;:!?])

Comment: This is the final complete regex in case someone wants to use it:
`(?i)((?<!\b(?:a\.d|a\.m|abbr|adj|adv|al|assn|ave|c|c\.v|ca|dept|dr|e\.g|est|etc|fig|gen|hon|hrs|i\.e|inc|jr|mr|mrs|ms|mt|no|obj|oz|p\.a|p\.m|p\.s|pl|poss|prep|prof|pron|pseud|r\.i\.p|rev|sing|sq|sr|st|stat|syn|trans|v|vb|vs))\.|[,;:!?])$`